# Use Local IP address to probe network

Tags: javascript, networking

So this past week I was busy researching ways in which I can scan SSDP in the browser and return the data to my webpage where I can display the information. However, I know this is impossible to do now. That being said, is there really no way I could probe my network to find all devices on the network that may be online. I know I could get my local IP address quite easily using Javascript and have got that working. Something that I could do in terminal is ping the IP address and then run `arp -a` which would return all other online devices on the network. Is there anyway I could do something similar using just Javascript? I know I can ping using Javascript but having trouble finding a replacement for the `arp` function (if it is even possible to do in Javascript).

My apologies if the question is badly worded. Let me know if any more clarification is needed. I know it may not be possible (most likely won't be) due to possible security issues but just wondering out of curiosity.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about JavaScript in a web browser or something like Node.js?

Comment: no, you can't from browser javascript. while JS has some native(ish) networking capabilities, e.g. websockets and ajax, it doesn't have a general purpose "do anything you want" network stack that would let you anywhere NEAR such low level data, nor should it. your local network specs are absolutely NO business whatsoever of whatever website you're visiting, but they'd be able to get that data if there was some local network stack allow JS access to the info.

Comment: I'm talking about Javascript in the browser. Hmm, so it is still not possible to probe for all other IPs in the network even if we know the local IP essentially due to security issues?

Comment: You could make your server probe the ips if the network you want is the same as your server

Comment: So let's say the network is the same as the server. How exactly would I be able to make the server probe all the IPs and then display these IPs in the browser? Not asking for any code, just some useful links/tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used any of the following methods, but this is what I found on the subject.

It seems that there is a browser [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ssdp-provider/pfdiljjcookjofjbjnbnkgfnfmnoljmk?hl=en) with a JS [library](https://github.com/jacobEAdamson/ssdp-chrome) which you can checkout. Together they provide SSDP service to chrome.

Another long, some what far fetch rout is to implement a UDP transport layer in Javascript (browser side). I would first look at [sipml5](https://github.com/sipml5/sipml5/tree/master/src/tinySIP/src/transports) transport layer see how they handled it. Even if you UDP part will work, which will be awesome, you will need to implement HTTPU and then SSDP.

Another possibility would be WebRTC (sipml5 use it too), but I didn't see other examples.